# Live USB boot within an existing virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, liveusb

I need to resize a partition on an Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine, so I'm trying to boot up a live USB operating system inside the virtual machine, and then re-size the hard disk partition using GParted. Is it possible to do this in Virtualbox, or is there some workaround for this problem (using a live CD or something similar?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ISO image. Just attach it to the VM and boot from it.

Comment: How should I attach the iso image to the VM, in this case? What steps are involved?

Comment: I added the iso image to "Controller: IDE" under the "Storage" tab, and it worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. As I know, there is no possibility to attach an image as a USB device in virtual machines.

Comment: Also there is possibility to attach ISO to a virtual CD-ROM drive in VM.